# Can not find ses.php while using php-aws-ses sdk for Amazon SES

Tags: php, amazon-ses

I am trying to use this simple library for using amazon email service.
the library is [here](https://github.com/daniel-zahariev/php-aws-ses) The example shown requires ses.php but I can not find where the ses.php is. I have also tried on the author's website which is [here](http://www.orderingdisorder.com/aws/ses/). But still got no idea where this comes from. Is it some standard file to be downloaded from amazon AWS sdk ?

Any help would be apprecaited.

Comment: why dont you just use the [sdk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/installation.html) coming from the site (amazon) itself?

Comment: @kevinabelita The AES sdk is installed via shell and has lots of redundant things that I do not need. Would suit if I had an exclusive standlane machine likeamazon EC2 etc. I am using a shared hosting and only need SES feature which are coverd by this small library.

Comment: yeah the sdk coming from the site has the complete sdk so it might not  specifically fit on your situation, good thing the author replied. good work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developer daniel-zahariev has now resolved the issue in the repo after I sent him my inquiry. instead of using ses.php need to include following files

```
 require_once('SimpleEmailService.php');
 require_once('SimpleEmailServiceMessage.php');
 require_once('SimpleEmailServiceRequest.php');
```